# Angular Reactive Forms binding two field in seperate Forms

Tags: angular, forms, binding, reactive

i would like two bind to values in two seperate reactive forms.
So i have one component as main witch includes two seperate components like component one and component two. In each of them are a form.
So, in component one a field name - also in component two.
When i change the value from one field it has to be bind to the other.
Maybe here's someone who can gave me a small hint how to do that.

Comment: what have you tried so far where is the code?

Comment: basic component interaction is explained in details at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction. I would suggest to read the documentation first, then try it yourself, then ask other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your qeustion it look like you have two individual component on you html page , and want to provide interaction between them.

To achieve this you should **Making use of shared service , between compoenent** which allows interaction.

you should follow this :  [Communicate between component via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service), article also list other ways to communicate , have look.

Comment: yes, thats exactly i want to do. Thanks for your hint. i will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Create a Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentInteractionService {
  public name = new Subject<string>();
}
```

Component A:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ComponentInteractionService } from '../../services/component-interaction.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-eins',
  templateUrl: './form-eins.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-eins.component.css']
})
export class FormEinsComponent implements OnInit {

  formEins: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private ci: ComponentInteractionService) { }

  submit() {
    this.ci.name.next(this.formEins.get("nameEins").value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.formEins = this.fb.group({
      nameEins: ''
    });

    this.ci.name.subscribe( 
      data => { this.formEins.get("nameEins").setValue(data); }
    );   

  }

}
```

Component B:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ComponentInteractionService } from '../../services/component-interaction.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-zwei',
  templateUrl: './form-zwei.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-zwei.component.css']
})
export class FormZweiComponent implements OnInit {

  formZwei: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private ci: ComponentInteractionService) { }

  submit() {
    this.ci.name.next(this.formZwei.get("nameEins").value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.formZwei = this.fb.group({
      nameEins: ''
    });

    this.ci.name.subscribe( 
      data => { this.formZwei.get("nameEins").setValue(data); }
    ); 

  }

}
```